# Pure text web browser for Android?

Tags: android, web-browser, internet

On Linux I used to use pure text internet browsers in the terminal. I need one for Android, perhaps in an app. From the US, I'm trying to access the Russian internet like http://en.kremlin.ru/ and all the sites take like 5+ minutes to load and I figure if I used a pure text browser it would take less time.

Comment: What comes to mind (not tried, just brain-storming) is using Termux and install Lynx in there. Provided they have that package.

Comment: @Izzy Termux worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. First I installed Termux, which is like a Linux terminal in Android. For that I used F-Droid by going [here](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/), installing the F-Droid client, and then installing Termux. Then I followed [these instruction](https://www.learntermux.tech/2020/01/best-way-to-browser-internet-using-Termux-on-Android-2020.html) to install the web browser.